# Dynamically populating dropdown menu based on selection without a submit button

Tags: python, json, web, frontend, backend

I have a large dataset of car makes and models. In my web application, I want to create a form where the user can select a car make from the first dropdown menu, and based on the selected make, the second dropdown menu will be populated with the corresponding models. The goal is to achieve this without the need for a submit button.

To accomplish this, I have manipulated the dataset using Pandas and created a JSON file that contains the models for each unique car make. I plan to use JavaScript to handle the dynamic population of the second dropdown menu based on the selected make.

Here's what I have so far:

The original dataset is in Pandas format.
I have transformed the data and stored the models for each make in a JSON file.
I'm familiar with using JavaScript and HTML to create forms and handle events.
However, I'm struggling with the implementation details. Specifically, I'm unsure how to detect when a car model is selected from the initial dropdown menu and dynamically update the options in the second dropdown menu accordingly.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, code examples, or recommended libraries to accomplish this task effectively. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have tried a mouse down event Listener but I kind of figured that wouldn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.